# Codeigniter error with chatset latin1 (Vbulletin)

Tags: codeigniter, vbulletin, latin1

**i using codeigniter make an project, it as follow.**
i want to connect to mysql of Vbulletin and show in my project, i save code with **UTF-8** not **DOM**, it show ok but i see at Chrome and IE error **HEAD** haven't everything.
but only **TITLE** in **HEAD** and everything after **BODY**. and have space in "" after BODY

**i config database.php in codeigniter is.**

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';//utf8
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';//utf8_general_ci
```

i use latin1 because Vbulletin use it.

**Html page**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="author" content="mr.sam" />
```

and i try to change chatset is (latin1 or utf-8).
BUT IT NOT WORK
Please help me THANKS ALL

Answer (score 1):

This is good/common question... Put this in index.php:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8", true);
```

or

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = "iso-8859-1";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "latin1_general_ci";
```

in config.php.

Else, checkout this page: http://hash-bang.net/2009/02/utf8-with-codeigniter/

Comment: i tried to edit but it not work, i hope you can try to help me. Thanks